# The dom list renders unwanted comma or quotations marks

Tags: javascript, html, dom

for my current code renders coma, quotation marks between my list items, not sure what the issue please help.

I change the code to this for it to be easier to read:
"null" in tinary operator works and changing it doesn't affect the problem or result.
(currentCollection[indexOf item].Words are an array of words and regex = /[a-z]/g)

```
 for (let i = 0; i < currentCollection.length; i++) {
    let words = currentCollection[i].Words.join(" ")
    elementsString += `<div><h2>${currentCollection[i].name}</h2>
     <ul>
     
     ${currentCollection[i].Words.map(word => regex.test(word) ? (`<li>${word}</li>`) : null

    )}</ul></div>`
```

Comment: `map` will return an array. You may want to `join` the result into a string.

Comment: If I join them, it will render a single list item of words, instead of list items in currentCollection[i].Words array

Comment: Can you post an example of the `collection` input your code is meant to be transforming to your question?

Comment: Collection is gathered form external data that pass query. The collection contains an six  objects in this format {id:'1' name: 'Alpaca', Words:['a'. 'b'] }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do something like this. I'm not sure what that `test` is meant to do so I left it out. But I added some CSS to make it look pretty.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Alpaca', words:['a', 'b'] },
  { id: 2, name: 'Moose', words:['c', 'd'] },
  { id: 3, name: 'Tiger', words:['e', 'f'] },
  { id: 4, name: 'Sparrow', words:['g', 'h'] }
];

// `map` over the array of words to create a
// list of items
function getItems(words) {
 return words.map(word => {
    return `<li>${word}</li>`;
  }).join('');
}

// `map` over the array to create a heading
// and a list of items in an unordered list element
const html = arr.map(obj => {
  const { name, words } = obj;
  return `
    <div>
      <h2>${name}<h2>
      <ul>${getItems(words)}</ul>
    </div>
  `;
}).join('');

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
h2 { font-size: 1em; }
ul { font-weight: 400; list-style: none; margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0; }
li { padding: 0.2em; margin-left: 0.5em; text-transform: uppercase; }
li:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: #ffff00; }
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Thanks, the test was there to get only words in array.  I see now, so the join is there to remove the commas from the the answers, as it converts array in to a single string?

Comment: Yes. That's right @MatthewsMasia. The `join` is to join the array into a string.